# Sending Retrofit Object To New Activity

Tags: javascript, android, android-activity, interface, retrofit2

I am trying to develop an android app, I am using Retrofit2 for handling all my network stuff and communication with the server.
I have a main activity and I also have login activity.
I am initializing the Retrofit on the main activity and I am trying to send the login activity the retrofit initialized interface and then things got hard.
According to a little research I can't just send the retrofit stuff to the new activity with '.putextra(...)' function.
I will be happy to get some help with that.

**My Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   final UserService userConnection;
    userConnection = ApiUtils.getUserService();


    Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    toolBar.setTitle("Welcome @PlaceHolder");
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);

   startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
//    Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
//    i.putExtra("userConnection", (Serializable) userConnection);
//    startActivity(i);


    ScrollView feed = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.feedView);

    //LinearLayOut Setup
    LinearLayout feed1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.feed);
    Feed feed2 = new Feed(this,feed1);
    feed1 = feed2.getFeed();

    //***************************************************//

    Call call = userConnection.getResponse();
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                ResObj resObj = (ResObj) response.body();
                if(resObj.getpostID().equals("12Aa")){
                    //login start main activity
                    //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                   // intent.putExtra("username", "tomer");
                    //startActivity(intent);
                    Log.e("Error is blabla: ","Yes");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The username or password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("Error is blabla: ",response.toString());

                }
                Log.e("Error is blabla: ",response.message().toString());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error! Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Error is blabla: ",response.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Error is blabla: ",t.toString());
        }
    });



}
```

}

**My Login Activity:**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
   final UserService userConnection =(UserService)getIntent.getSerializableExtra("userConnection");


    Button loginBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    EditText emailBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailBox);
    EditText passBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passBox);

    final String email = emailBox.getText().toString();
    final String password = passBox.getText().toString();

    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Call login = userConnection.login(email,password);
            login.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, retrofit2.Response response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        ResObj resObj = (ResObj) response.body();
                        if(resObj.loginStatus().equals("connected")){
                            Log.e("Login Status: ","Success");
                            finish();
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.e("Login Status: ","Wrong Password or Email");
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("Login Status: ","Faild To Recieve Server Message");

                }
            });

        }
    });

    Button registerBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
        registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void  onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class));
            }
    });

}
```

}

**The UserService Interface:**

```
public interface UserService{

@GET("/testDB")
Call<ResObj> getResponse(
);

@POST("/login")
Call<ResObj> login(@Query("userEmail") String userEmail,
                   @Query("userPassword") String userPassword);
```

}

**The ApiUtiles Class:**

```
public class ApiUtils {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://**.***.***.***:****";

public static UserService getUserService(){
    return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(UserService.class);
}
```

}

I will be happy to get solution or guide of how to send retrofit interfaces between activities :)

Comment: Why do even want to send `userConnection` to `LoginActivity`? Why don't you create and initialize that object in `LoginActivity` like you did it in `MainActivity`?

Comment: Because in order to make Call object at the login activity I need UserService Interface.
Moreover, the app needs communication with the server also at the main activity since it's going to be some kind of chatting app.

Comment: `Because in order to make Call object at the login activity I need UserService Interface` That's what I asked in my previous comment "Why don't you create an object of API interface in LoginActivity?". Passing an object of API Interface from one activity to another doesn't make any sense IMO.

Comment: So you are saying it's better to me to create object of API interface at the login activity and also other new API interface based object at the main activity?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely :)

Comment: @Shashanth
Thanks man, You just did saved my project.
What about the `Call`object, should I create new one for each activity or it can be passed between activities(with `.putExtra()` function)?

Comment: Don't need to pass it between activities. Just create new objects of `Call` wherever you want.